# Insert values into array based on key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, key

I have a function producing this kind of array:

> Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => home
>   [slug] => home [2] => [parent_id] =>
>   [3] => 1 [publish] => 1 [4] => content
>   [type] => content
>
> [id_2] => Array (
>   [0] => 2 [id] => 2 [1] => 404_error
>   [slug] => 404_error [2] => 1
>   [parent_id] => 1 [3] => 1 [publish] =>
>   1 [4] => content [type] => content ) )

I need a function that will allow me to find id_x in this array and append a new array in the array it occurs in, regardless of the deph where the desired id_x key is.

e.g like this

> Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => home
>   [slug] => home [2] => [parent_id] =>
>   [3] => 1 [publish] => 1 [4] => content
>   [type] => content
>
> [id_2] => Array (
>   [0] => 2 [id] => 2 [1] => 404_error
>   [slug] => 404_error [2] => 1
>   [parent_id] => 1 [3] => 1 [publish] =>
>   1 [4] => content [type] => content
>
> [id_3] => Array ( [0] => 3
>   [id] => 3 [1] => generic [slug] =>
>   generic [2] => 2 [parent_id] => 2 [3]
>   => 1 [publish] => 1 [4] => forms [type] => forms ) ) ) )

I.E Where [parent_id] matches id_x, insert a new array.

I've looked in the manual and nothing seems entirely appropiate.

var_export on the current array:

> array ( 'id_1' => array ( 0 => '1',
>   'id' => '1', 1 => 'home', 'slug' =>
>   'home', 2 => '', 'parent_id' => '', 3
>   => '1', 'publish' => '1', 4 => 'content', 'type' => 'content', 'id_2'
>   => array ( 0 => '2', 'id' => '2', 1 => '404_error', 'slug' => '404_error', 2
>   => '1', 'parent_id' => '1', 3 => '1', 'publish' => '1', 4 => 'content',
>   'type' => 'content', ), ), 'id_7' =>
>   array ( 0 => '7', 'id' => '7', 1 =>
>   'login_expiry', 'slug' =>
>   'login_expiry', 2 => '', 'parent_id'
>   => '', 3 => '1', 'publish' => '1', 4 => 'content', 'type' => 'content', 'id_4' => array ( 0 => '4', 'id' =>
>   '4', 1 => 'login_expiry', 'slug' =>
>   'login_expiry', 2 => '7', 'parent_id'
>   => '7', 3 => '0', 'publish' => '0', 4 => 'content', 'type' => 'content', ), ), 'id_2' => array ( 'id_3' => array (
>   0 => '3', 'id' => '3', 1 => 'generic',
>   'slug' => 'generic', 2 => '2',
>   'parent_id' => '2', 3 => '1',
>   'publish' => '1', 4 => 'forms', 'type'
>   => 'forms', ), ), 'id_4' => array ( 'id_5' => array ( 0 => '5', 'id' =>
>   '5', 1 => '404_error', 'slug' =>
>   '404_error', 2 => '4', 'parent_id' =>
>   '4', 3 => '1', 'publish' => '1', 4 =>
>   'content', 'type' => 'content', ), ),
>   'id_5' => array ( 'id_6' => array ( 0
>   => '6', 'id' => '6', 1 => 'generic', 'slug' => 'generic', 2 => '5',
>   'parent_id' => '5', 3 => '1',
>   'publish' => '1', 4 => 'forms', 'type'
>   => 'forms', ), ), )

Comment: include `var_export` will be much useful

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) will help you.

Comment: @YsoL8 format your question a bit and maybe I'll be able to help you more.